# WebService Client not connecting to WebService Server using HTTPS

Tags: java, web-services, https, jboss, jax-ws

I've deployed a WebService in JBoss AS7.1 that needs to use HTTPS.
I've configured the standalone.xml on the server in this way:

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl name="server-ssl" key-alias="server" password="secret" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/server.keystore" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>

<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
```

The keystore is in the right position, and I've added to my web.xml :

```
<security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>HTTPS Test</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
     </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The WebService is working and uses HTTPS, in fact I can verify it by accessing the URL from a web browser.

My problem is the client, that is deployed on another JBoss AS 7.1, and not works.
I've created the client from the wsdl, and modified the first part of the class WebServicesService so to use the https:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "WebServicesService", 
wsdlLocation = "https://192.168.1.104:8443/Server/WebServices?wsdl",
targetNamespace = "http://webservices.foo.it/") 
@HandlerChain(file="to-server-handler-chain.xml")

public class WebServicesService extends Service {

public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://webservices.foo.it/", "WebServicesService");
public final static QName WebServicesPort = new QName("http://webservices.foo.it/", "WebServicesPort");
static {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://192.168.1.104:8443/Server/WebServices?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WebServicesService.class.getName())
        .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "file");
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}

public WebServicesService(URL wsdlLocation) {

    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
}


public WebServicesService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public WebServicesService() {
    super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
}

//This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
//API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
//compliant code instead.
public WebServicesService(WebServiceFeature ... features) {
    super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
}

//This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
//API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
//compliant code instead.
public WebServicesService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
}

//This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
//API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
//compliant code instead.
public WebServicesService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     returns WebServices
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "WebServicesPort")
public WebServices getWebServicesPort() {
    return super.getPort(WebServicesPort, WebServices.class);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param features
 *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
 * @return
 *     returns WebServices
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "WebServicesPort")
public WebServices getWebServicesPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return super.getPort(WebServicesPort, WebServices.class, features);
}
```

}

When i try to make the first connection, the client JBoss prints:

```
[org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.resolver.JBossWSResourceResolver] (http--192.168.1.102-8080-1) Cannot open stream for resource: https://192.168.1.104:8433/Server/WebServices?wsdl
```

and then exceptions:

```
[org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http--192.168.1.102-8080-1) Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://192.168.1.104:8443/Server/WebServices?wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

What can be the problems that make my client not to connect to server using HTTPS?

Comment: if you're really sure the two machines can connect each other, there can be something related to the keystore/ssl certificates on the client. Have you checked the keystore ? And there's a typo in your URL :D

Comment: The two machines can connect, I'm sure because from a browser in the client I can go to the URL of the webservice using HTTPS. The typo error is not present in the class, only a mistake here :). Can you please tell me the procedures to make the keystore in the client working?

Comment: just out of interest, in your standalone.xml, you have the https set up as 8443, but in your other code you reference it as 8433, is this correct?

Comment: @kolin yes, that was stupid but I insert the wrong port. However now I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`, what can be the cause?

Comment: Its merely the certificate issue of keystore :)

Comment: @gk1017 what do you mean? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You've to add the public certificate in the keystore your Jboss client is using (by default it uses the cacerts of the JDK/JRE you're using to execute your Jboss: $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts, to add the certificate you can use the keytool command included in the JDK).

Comment: @ToniS.Magraner I've createad a client truststore using the server certificate, but I don't know where to put this truststore

Comment: I don't know if there is anyway to change the truststore just for one specific application deployed in Jboss, but you can redefine the truststore for the whole application server process defining the properties: javax.net.ssl.trustStore (pointint to the exact route of your truststore), and javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword (the password of the truststore). But notice that those properties will override the default configuration which is looking in the cacerts of the JRE. So, if you want to avoid configuring all those properties, just add the certificate to the Java cacerts file.

Comment: @ToniS.Magraner I always get the same exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` even if I add the server certificate to cacerts

Comment: Have you redirected http to https in jboss server ?if not please refer this [Follow Here](http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/jboss-tutorial-how-to-enable-ssl-https-on-jboss-as-well-as-other-nice-to-know-configurations/)